# Is it possible to transition <thead> and <tbody> to different opacities with borders?

Tags: html, css

I need to be able to transition a table's `<tbody>` and `<thead>` to different opacities (as part of a UX requirement). This doesn't sound problematic by itself except my table's rows contain a bottom border.

It seems that changing the opacity of `<td>` and `<th>` cells has no effect on their borders. I tried to work around this challenge by changing the border with alpha transparency border colors. Unfortunately, the border alpha transparency approach does not work while transitioning together with opacity.

Is there another way to work around this with pure CSS/HTML?

**An Example:**

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
 $('table').toggleClass('opaque');
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  opacity: 0.1;
  transition: border-color 2s linear, opacity 2s linear;
 }
 
.opaque td,  .opaque th {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="opaque">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>City</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Matthew</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>New York</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>Chicago</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>James</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Los Angeles</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button">Toggle Opacity</button>
```

Comment: If you run the code snippet without the border color change, you will see that the border does not change opacity with the rest of the cell.

Comment: I suspect this is due to the `border-collapse`...https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ZydjOm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a weird one.

It looks like the root cause of the issue is `border-collapse`: with collapsed borders, opacity on the parent `thead` and `tbody` elements won't work. I'm assuming that's due the adjacent cells in both the `thead` and `tbody` sharing collapsed borders.

If you don't use `border-collapse` and instead set `border-spacing` to `0` and then fiddle with adjacent cell borders, you can then achieve the effect you want by setting `opacity` directly on `thead` and `tbody`. Kind of awkward, but it works.

Comment: That works! Thanks for the tip on border-spacing. I don't think I would have tried that.